# How to shift a linked list's data? (in C)

Tags: c, linked-list

My question is simple and answers too rare. I know how to add or remove a node but how do you copy one previous node's data to the following node? Basically with an array the easiest way to shift it is to copy to the last element the previous element and move up the array like so:

```
for (i = number_of_elements ; i > 0; i--)
    tab[i] = tab[i-1];
```

Otherwise you would copy each element to the next and have the same data for each element which we don't want.

Then I can assign to tab[0] a new value.

But how to do that with a linked list? I know how to add a node to the beginning of the list:

```
struct node *node (struct node *head, int data)
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = head;
   // new_node->prev = ??

    return new_node;
}
```

which I assign to my list pointer so that it adds to the left. But I can't go up a linked list. Since the pointer next leads to the next node. Do I have to add a prev pointer to each node? But to what should it point? Thank you for helping in any way or for your rebuke because I just can't think properly.

edit: My idea then is to do simply as follows:

```
for (current = head; current!= NULL; current=current -> next) ;
```

and from there:

```
for( ; current!= head; current = current -> prev)
    current ->data = current -> prev -> data;
return head;
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Aren't you done?

Comment: Technically you don't have to malloc another node. You can reuse the last node. Unhook the last node from the list, hang it on the front, and set your new value there. The rest of the list can remain as-is if you perform your pointer housekeeping correctly.

Comment: Why are you trying to loop over the list and copy data between the nodes? What's the purpose?

Comment: It's for a snake game. Every half second each snake part has to move to where the previous snake part was before. So the data has to shift across the linked list constantly as the head of the snake keeps moving. New positions are acquired and the position of snake before the move has to be copied to snake->next. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
void Shift(node* Head) {
    type PrevData = Head->Data;
    Head = Head->Next;
    while (Head) {
        type Temp = Head->Data;
        Head->Data = PrevData;
        PrevData = Temp;
        Head = Head->Next;
    }
}
```